# How to capture packets from Hotspot Shield

Tags: c, packet-capture

How can I capture packet of applications, including Hotspot Shield and other free proxy applications?

Comment: What is the question, and how is it related to C/C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for a tool that allows you to capture network packets on your machine and examine them.

You can use tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) that allows you do that.